# How do I get the IP Address of my router?

Tags: networking, router, ip-address

How can I find the address of my router in my network?

Comment: http://ipkoala.com

Comment: internal address or external... or both?

Answer (score 3):

If you know the make and model of your router then you can google for a manual and it will have the default ip listed in it.  If you do not know the make and model you can try 192.168.1.1 as that is a typical default ip address for many routers.  If none of this works you can go to the command prompt (WIN+R then type cmd) and enter the command `ipconfig`.  Your default gateway is typically the ip address of your router.  This all assumes you want the LAN ip, not the WAN ip.  If you want the WAN ip of your router just google `whats my ip address` and you will get it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using DHCP, simply check your routing table.  In most operating systems `netstat -rn` will provide that list, then you're looking for a line like:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.10     20
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends where the router is located:

- If you are hooked directly into the router, you can run the `tracert` command in a command prompt, followed by any external IP. The first hop on the list will be your default gateway (the router you're hooked into). Alternatively, looking under the 'ipconfig' command for a default gateway will give the same result.
- You can reset the router and then check the documentation for the default IP address
- If you are looking for the external (public) ip of said router, you can check on some site such as http://checkip.dyndns.org/

If it's located elsewhere on the network, or isn't your default gateway, it gets a bit more tricky. Is that so?

Answer (score 2):

If you are behind that router and are looking for the external IP you can always check sites like http://www.whatismyip.com/

Answer (score 2):

In a command prompt:

```
ipconfig | find Gateway
```